# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') - chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

[image]

I'm trying to build an extension to monitor the xhr portion of the devtools network tab.  With some help , I have been able to get the requests to be displayed on the service-worker console and I can log the Post requests. My next step is to send some post info to the extension popup. However I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
```

manifest.json:

```
{
 "manifest_version": 3,
 "version": "1.0",
 "name": "Hello World!",
   "description": "Learning how to make a chrome extension!",
 "icons": {
"16": "images/puppy16.png",
"48": "images/puppy48.png",
"128": "images/puppy128.png"
},
"action": {
"default_icon": "images/puppy.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"background": {
"service_worker": "background.js"
},
"host_permissions": ["*://*.cnn.com/", "],
"permissions": ["webRequest", "activeTab","tabs"],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["*://cnn.com/*"],
  "js": ["contentScript.js"]
  }
 ]
}
```

In my background.js:

```
(function () {

var tab
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, 
function (tabs) {
    tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab);
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (details) {   
        
        // Use this to decode the body of your post
        const postedString = decodeURIComponent(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,
            new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)));
        console.log(postedString)
        const body = JSON.parse(postedString);
        console.log(body.CenterPoint.Point);
    },
    { urls: [url] },
    ["requestBody"]

);
 console.log(tab);
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "your message")    ...
```

My content script is:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(message, callback) {
     console.log("message received")
}
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where do you set the variable `tab`?

Comment: sorry, updated now.

Comment: tab is being set asynchronously. You should move the code that relies on tab inside of your .query() callback